# AngularJS - How do I save text from an input area? localStorage?

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, local-storage

So I am adding a notes area for the user. The user will be able to input whatever they want and hit save. Save works for the entire page, except for the input area it resets. The only other thing I can think of is `ui-tinymce` or `localStorage`?? Either way any input on how to save and store the input area div? Also, it should be done on the same page due to it pertaining to a specific order. Each order will have different notes in their input area.

HTML

```
<div ng-if="'confirmation' != page && editable" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3>Notes</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div align="center">
               <input  placeholder="Notes" ng-model="myNotes.notes" class="notes">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.myNotes = {};
```

**Update**: Let me add more to this issue. So I got it working, kind of, I am able to successfully save my 'ui-tiny-mce' with a post call. I'll post below the working page which is saving the text from the 'ui-tiny-mce'. Now the issue is, it saves the text. However each order has a 'ui-tiny-mce' box and when I save one, it saves the same data to all the 'ui-tiny-mce' boxes in all the orders pages.

HTML

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Notes <button ng-click="saveNotes()">Save Notes</button></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions2" ng-model="myNotes.notes"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS Controller

```
  $scope.myNotes = {};
  $scope.saveNotes = function () {
        $http.post('api/settingsController.php/write',$scope.settings).success(function () {
            toastr.success('Notes Saved');
        });
    };
```

PHP

```
$app->post('/write', function(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request) use ($app) {
$document = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
unset($document['_id']);

$document['sid'] = $_SESSION['sid'];
$app['mongoOrders']->update(['sid'=>$_SESSION['sid']], $document, ['upsert'=>true]);

return $app->json($document);});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an Angular module, ngStorage that makes it a little simpler to use local storage - basically you can bind your data to a localstorage element.

https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Answer (score 0):

UI Tinymce is a framework for editing text in browsers, while local storage is a solution for temporary data storage... They're not comparable. You could use UI Tinymce for editing and then local storage for saving the data from UI Tinymce, which could work. Although you should be forewarned that using local storage (or any client-side storage solution) only works until the use clears their browser cache/cookies/storage. If you're planning on making a web application, a better solution would be to store the data on an indexed database on the server that's serving your application instead. That way the user's can't accidentally delete their data. You can even still use UI Tinymce.

Comment: Yeah I'm saving it now, but now its saving data from one 'ui-tiny-mce' box and populating them in each page that should have unique notes in there.

Comment: How are you retrieving the notes and filling them into the textareas? Also, does the ui-tiny-mce box keep the notes if you refresh?

Comment: Through my /write route which is triggered from my saveOrders function. Yes if I refresh or leave the page and come back the notes are there.

Comment: Could it be that your /write route calls with a fixed ID instead of an ID that is tied to individual orders? Without seeing the function itself I can't say for certain.

Answer (score -1):

So, you have a few options if you want to keep the data even after refreshing the page.

**Option 1 (good):**

Save the current note, and access it via **route**. You'll want to make sure that **ngRoute** has been added to your app's modules:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

and that you've added **ngRoute** to your scripts:

```
<script src="path/to/angular-route.js"></script>  // must be loaded in after angular.js
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

, then add the route to your config:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

**Option 2 (okay):**

Save the note as Stringified JSON that's added to the **window.localStorage** object.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

The issue with this option, is it's more prone to having stale data.

**Option 3 (not so good)**:

Append the note to the window object directly.

Comment: When a user types in their notes, I want to save their input so if they leave the page and come pack their notes are still there. I'm just curious what is the best way to save their input.